# 2d Array containing objects

Tags: java, object, multidimensional-array

This is an assignment for class that involves creating a hotel guest service. I created the 2d array below with 8 "floors", 20 "rooms", and populated them with `Room` objects. I am currently trying to use nested for-loops to go through each Room object and assign it a room number. For example, floor 1 would contain rooms 101-120.

The class below is a test class that I am using.

```
public class Test {

    public Test() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**
          * Creates a two dimensional array with 8 rows and 20 columns
          */
        Room [][] hotelBuild = new Room[8][20];
        /**
          * populates the 2d array with Room objects
          */
        for (int floor=0; floor<hotelBuild.length; floor++) {
            for (int room=0; room<hotelBuild[floor].length; room++) {
                hotelBuild[floor][room] = new Room();
                /**
                 * used to print out contents of 2d array
                 */
                //System.out.print(hotelBuild[floor][room]=new Room());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is class `Room` that contains the variables, setters, getters, as well as the `toString()` override method.

```
public class Room {

//Instance variables

    /**
     *the rooms number
     */
    private int roomNumber;

    /** is the room occupied or not
     *
     */
    private boolean isOccupied;

    /** name of guest
     *
     */
    private String guest;

    /** cost per day
     *
     */
    private double costPerDay;

    /** number of days guest is staying
     *
     */
    int days;

    //Constructors
    public Room(){
    }
    /** Construct a room with values above
     *
     */
    public Room(int room, boolean nonVacant, String guestName, double cost, int day) {
        roomNumber = room;
        isOccupied = nonVacant;
        guest = guestName;
        costPerDay = cost;
        days = day;
    }

    // getters

    /** gets roomNumber
     *
     */
    public int getRoomNumber(){
        return roomNumber;
    }

    /** gets isOccupied
     *
     */
    public boolean getIsOccupied(){
        return isOccupied;
    }

    /** gets guest
     *
     */
    public String getGuest(){
        return guest;
    }

    /** gets costPerDay
     *
     */
    public double getCostPerDay(){
        return costPerDay;
    }

    /** gets days
     *
     */
    public int getDays(){
        return days;
    }

    // setters

    /** sets isOccupied
     *
     */
    public void setIsOccupied(boolean full){
        this.isOccupied = full;
    }

    /** sets days
     *
     */
    public void setDays(int numDays){
        this.days = numDays;
    }

    /** sets guest name
     *
     */
    public void setGuest(String name){
        this.guest = name;
    }

    /** formats output depending if room is occupied or not
     *
     */

    public String toString(){
        if(isOccupied == true){
            return "Room number: " + roomNumber + "\n"+ "Guest name: "
                + guest + "\n"+ "Cost : " + costPerDay
                + "\n"+ "Days: " + days + "\n";
        }
        else{
            return "Room number " + roomNumber
                + " costs " + costPerDay + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

How do I assign each `Room` object in the array a unique room number?

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: How do I assign each Room object in the array a unique room number?

Comment: Well you need a setter on room number if you only care about room number. If you specifically want the 1st floor to contain rooms 101-120 then you just have to calculate ((1+floor)*100)+1+room and set the value

Comment: If you want a way to put the numbers in the correct order then use auxiliar variables. Use a count for know what floor it is (it will be increased at the end of the first loop). Then room number is Floor * 100 + another variable you reset to 1 at the begining of the first loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
for (int floor=0; floor<hotelBuild.length; floor++){
    for (int room=0; room<hotelBuild[floor].length; room++){
        Room r = new Room();
        r.setRoomNumber(
           cleverCalculationWithFloorAndRoomNr(floor, room));
        hotelBuild[floor][room]= r;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a way to put the numbers in the correct order then use the varables you alredady have. Use a count for know what floor it is (it will be increased at the end of the first loop). Then room number is Floor * 100 + another variable you reset to 1 at the begining of the first loop. Just a hint to help you. Fill the gaps ;)

```
int floorNumber = 1;
int roomNumber = 1;
for (int floor=0; floor<hotelBuild.length; floor++){
        for (int room=0; room<hotelBuild[floor].length; room++){
            hotelBuild[floor][room]=new Room();

                            /**
                             * used to print out contents of 2d array
                             */
            //System.out.print(hotelBuild[floor][room]=new Room());
            //Add room number here.
            //Increase room number

        }
  //floorNumber increase
  //roomNumber reset
    }
```

Once you have achieved this you could try to use the variables you have in the loops (room and floor) with a few minor changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int floor=0; floor<hotelBuild.length; floor++){
    for (int room=0; room<hotelBuild[floor].length; room++){
        hotelBuild[floor][room]=new Room();
        // room number format: xxyy, x = floor, y = room
        // this assumes maximum 99 rooms per floor, it should be enough
        hotelBuild[floor][room].setNumber((floor + 1) * 100 + room + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it through the contructor for example or set with a setter in your class Room (classroom ahahah)

for example:

```
for (int floor=0; floor<hotelBuild.length; floor++){
        for (int room=0; room<hotelBuild[floor].length; room++){
            hotelBuild[floor][room]=new Room((floor+1)*100+room+1);
        }
    }
```

And in your Room class, you can add a constructor with only the room number as parameter

```
class Room{
  public Room(int roomNumber){
    this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
  }
...
}
```

Comment: class Room...classroom, I have sudden realization   8U